# Initializing an object ByRef

Tags: vb.net, initialization, byref

I don't have much experience with VB.NET and although I've searched, I can't find an answer to the following:

Say I have a `Dim myVar As MyClass`, and then a function in which I intend to initialize it such as `Public Sub MyInit(ByRef myVar As MyClass)`. Attempting to call this method is giving me a null reference error in the compiler, stating that I should initialize the variable first (but I intend to put that functionality in my method!).

Any thoughts in how I could achieve what I'm attempting here?

PS: I reckon it'd make more sense to create an `Initialize()` method in `MyClass`, or to make a `Public Function MyClassInitialize() As MyClass`, but in my particular scenario this is not possible.

Comment: one way to avoid it is to give myVar more scope so you dont have to pass it (a NullReference) to anything or anywhere to initialize it. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting it to `Nothing` first? (`Dim myVar As MyClass = Nothing`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just worried about the `Variable 'myVar' is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value` warning, you can just change the declaration to `Dim myVar as MyClass = Nothing`.

If you're writing the `MyInit` sub, you could also turn it into a function that returns an instance of `MyClass`:

```
Public Function MyInit() As MyClass
    Dim myLocalVar As New MyClass()
    '... initialization here
    Return myLocalVar
End Function

...

Dim myVar As MyClass = MyInit()
```